# Angular.js 1.2+ animation issue on leave

Tags: angularjs, css-animations

I have a issue with angular antimation and routs.
I have made 2 pages that when you click on a link button the new page should slide in from right and when you than click back the old page should slide back from the left.

The first animation when switching to new page works. But when clicking back something strange happens and i can't figure out whats the issue..
My css looks like this:

```
    /* menu ------------------------ */
.menu.ng-leave        {
    -webkit-animation:slideOutLeft 0.5s both ease-in;
    -moz-animation:slideOutLeft 0.5s both ease-in;
    animation:slideOutLeft 0.5s both ease-in;   
}
.menu.ng-enter      {  
    -webkit-animation:slideInLeft 0.5s both ease-in;
    -moz-animation:slideInLeft 0.5s both ease-in;
    animation:slideInLeft 0.5s both ease-in;    
}
/* slide in from the right */
@keyframes slideInRight {
    from    { transform:translateX(100%); }
    to      { transform: translateX(0); }
}
@-moz-keyframes slideInRight {
    from    { -moz-transform:translateX(100%); }
    to      { -moz-transform: translateX(0); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideInRight {
    from    { -webkit-transform:translateX(100%); }
    to      { -webkit-transform: translateX(0); }
}
/* slide out right */
@keyframes slideOutRight {
    to      { transform: translateX(100%); }
}
@-moz-keyframes slideOutRight { 
    to      { -moz-transform: translateX(100%); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideOutRight {
    to      { -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); }
}

/* Issue ------------------------ */
.issue.ng-leave        {
    -webkit-animation:slideOutRight 0.5s both ease-in;
    -moz-animation:slideOutRight 0.5s both ease-in;
    animation:slideOutRight 0.5s both ease-in;   
}
.issue.ng-enter         {  
    -webkit-animation:slideInRight 0.5s both ease-in;
    -moz-animation:slideInRight 0.5s both ease-in;
    animation:slideInRight 0.5s both ease-in;    
}
/* slide in from the left */
@keyframes slideInLeft {
    from    { transform:translateX(-100%); }
    to      { transform: translateX(0); }
}
@-moz-keyframes slideInLeft {
    from    { -moz-transform:translateX(-100%); }
    to      { -moz-transform: translateX(0); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideInLeft {
    from    { -webkit-transform:translateX(-100%); }
    to      { -webkit-transform: translateX(0); }
}
/* slide out left */
@keyframes slideOutLeft {
    to      { transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
@-moz-keyframes slideOutLeft {  
    to      { -moz-transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideOutLeft {
    to      { -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
```

I have made a [Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/BffONYoimy7B9vLzkHzc?p=info)!

So if you click on the big red square it animate to new page. Than click on the "back" link you will see the issue.

I also have a issue when clicking on the blue square nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the back link to

```
<a href="#/" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">BACK</a>
```

And in regards to the blue box. You have a spelling error in templateUrl (i.e. ttemplateUrl)

Comment: Great! I been starring at the code for 2 hours and didnt see that :/